# How to pass spatio-temporal data into sklearn models?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, interpolation, random-forest

I am new to machine learning and trying to master my first steps with scikit-learn. I would like to calculate an interpolation, based on spatio-temporal sensor data. I have a larger number of measuring stations that all measure data at the same time (hourly). For each measuring station I have a unique coordinate (X, Y, Z). My measured/fixed values for each measuring station thus consist of:

```
     Timestamp,          X,           Y,        Z,   Value + Possible further values
2018-05-04 00:00:00, 32362422.00, 5656123.00, 54.28, 4.28, ..
2018-05-04 00:00:00, 32365418.00, 5656413.00, 72.47, 3.12, ..
2018-05-04 00:00:00, 32360290.00, 5656973.00, 51.11, 2.50, ..
...
2018-05-04 01:00:00, 32362422.00, 5656123.00, 54.28, 4.53, ..
2018-05-04 01:00:00, 32365418.00, 5656413.00, 72.47, 3.27, ..
...

(train data)
```

(All data is available as a CSV file).

I want to interpolate values for coordinates between my measuring stations.
Of course, the values to be interpolated should depend on new values not yet known to the model

```
Sensor Data again
2018-05-22 16:00:00, 32362422.00, 5656123.00, 54.28, 0.29, ..
2018-05-22 16:00:00, 32365418.00, 5656413.00, 72.47, 1.12, ..
2018-05-22 16:00:00, 32360290.00, 5656973.00, 51.11, 0.73, ..
... -> All Measurements

New data to be interpolated in a grid:
2018-05-22 16:00:00, 32362500.00, 5656150.00, 55.81, ?, ..
2018-05-22 16:00:00, 32362500.00, 5656200.00, 56.44, ?, ..
...
(interpolation data)
```

For the calculation I would like to use the Random Forest Regressor.

However, I'm a bit overwhelmed:

1. How can I pass my data as summarized blocks (with identical timestamp) to my model?
2. How do I best validate such records? Also for the cross-validation my data must be bundled?

I am very grateful for any advice. The answers may also be somewhat detailed.
Cheers.

EDIT:

1. Of course, my labels are the values measured by the stations.
2. I tried a One-Hot-Encoding for each timestamp (equal time = same group). In next step want to predict a value for each coordinate of my digital elevation model.
3. Not yet, i thought RF would create the simpliest/best model. I will try it at next.

Comment: RF is a supervised model. It requires that you have labels for the expected/correct results for your training data. Do you have that?

Comment: There are no position parameters or RF, so your interpolation model would only be valid for one particular location. Which does not seem very useful for your sensor problem?

Comment: Have you tried a linear interpolation method (in 3d)? If not, definetely start with that